# typescript compiler option for resolving scss imports

Tags: typescript, commonjs, typescript2.0

I am using the following compiler options for a tool I am making and I am seeing an error when the compiler can't find the compiled scss file.

In other words, I have the following files:

- ClassA.tsx

  - This file has the line: `import styles from './ClassA.module.scss';`
- ClassA.module.scss

After the files are compiled I have the files:

- ClassA.js

  - This file has the line: `var ClassA_module_scss_1 = require('./ClassA.module.scss');`
- Class.module.scss.js

And I am seeing the error: `Cannot find module ClassA.module.scss`

These are my compiler options:

```
compilerOptions: {
    target: typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    module: typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    moduleResolution: typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    rootDir: this.buildConfig.rootPath,
    declaration: true,
    experimentalDecorators: true,
    jsx: typescript.JsxEmit.React,
    sourceMap: true
  }
```

Is there something special I must do to resolve the scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing assets or stylesheets is not a feature supported by TypeScript itself. For this to work, you need some module bundler that is aware of non-typescript/javascript imports like images or scss files. Webpack is such a tool that handles imports of assets and can do much more for you.

http://webpack.github.io/

When integrating webpack, you need the corresponding loaders to enable support for scss. You can find more details on configuring it to enable this at [sass-loader docs](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#apply-via-webpack-config). Before you should definitely have a look at the webpack docs to get a general understanding of how webpack and the loaders work. This can be somehow confusing in the beginning.

Please be aware that currently version 2 of webpack is still in development and you may encounter some tutorials that don't work for version 1.